# how to evaluate $ \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan \left(x \pm \sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{x+1} d x $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

how to evaluate
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan \left(x \pm \sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{x+1} d x
$$
Denote:
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{x+1} \,dx \\
J &= \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan \left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{x+1} \,dx \\
\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right) &=-1 \Rightarrow\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)=\frac{-1}{\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)} \\
\Rightarrow \arctan \left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right) &=-\arctan \left(\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&I+\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)+\arctan \left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{x+1} \,dx \\
= &\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan \left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}+x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}{1-\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}\right)}{x+1} \,dx \\
=& \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan \left(\frac{2x}{1-\left(x^2-\left(x^2-1\right)\right)}\right)}{x+1} \,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan (x)}{x+1} \,dx
\end{align*}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Integrate by parts

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1} \left(x +\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{x+1} d x\\
=& \ \tan^{-1}\left(x +\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\ln(1+x)\bigg|_0^1 -\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx\\
=&\ \frac{3\pi}8\ln2 - \frac12\cdot\frac\pi8\ln2=\frac{5\pi}{16}\ln2\\
\end{align}
Simplilarly
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1} \left(x -\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{x+1} d x=-\frac{3\pi}{16}\ln2\\
\end{align}

Comment: really quick (+1)

Answer (score 6):

Noting
$$ (x+\sqrt{x^2+1})(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)=1 $$
one has
$$\begin{eqnarray}
I+J &=& \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)+\arctan \left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{x+1} \,dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{x+1}\,dx=\frac18\pi\ln2\\ 
I-J &=& \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)-\arctan \left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{x+1} \,dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{\frac\pi2}{x+1}\,dx=\frac12\pi\ln2
\end{eqnarray}$$
and hence
$$ I=\frac{5\pi}{16}\ln2,J=-\frac{3\pi}{16}\ln2.$$